# semaphore like synchronization in ISR (Interrupt service routine)

Tags: c, message-queue, semaphore, interrupt

I have a queue where the put and pull functions of the queue are called when different interrupts happen. Is there a way to prevent race condition in this scenario?
While we can not wait on semaphores in interrupt service routines what is the best way to create a similar functionality. 
We are using an ARM-Cortex A5 processor of a Zynq FPGA to develope the code.

Comment: C doesn't know about ISRs, you should be more specific about the platform and ideally show some compilable example code. In a very simple scenario, it could be enough to prevent interrupts while inside the ISR.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Thanks for your comment I will update it

Comment: Note - you can certainly POST a semaphore unit from an ISR - it's the most common way of signaling a thread that I/O has completed.  It's true that you must not try to wait:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that each interrupt causes the "Interrupt Disabled" state of the processor to be turned on, and assuming that the interrupts you are handling have the same priority (that is, one can't interrupt the execution of the other), then there already can be no race condition and your ISRs can just access the shared queue.

(When an interrupt occurs, the processor goes into interrupt disabled mode, pushes all registers onto the stack, jumps to the ISR entry point and continues execution there. Once the ISR is done, the "iret" instruction does the reverse of the entry. This simple description can be implemented differently in different processors and platforms.)

Comment: Note that the shared queue index manipulation must be such that the ISR can push safely no matter what stage of a pop might be in progress from a driver-handler thread.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit, you are absolutely right. Fortunately here the queue seems only accessed in the ISRs. Otherwise the non-ISR accesses should themselves execute an interrupt disable instruction for safe access.