# How to implement a message queue in standard C

Tags: c, message-queue, stm32

I have a project (micro controller STM32 using c code) where I need to receive messages from serial port (for example strings) and I need to put the messages in a queue where I will read the string later.

Can someone tell me where can I find some example on **how to create a message queue** (like FIFO) of strings (or byte array) using **standard C** and how to  manage the queue? Thanks for any kind of support.

Comment: Did you search, "stm32 fifo queue".

Comment: link "not found"

Comment: Do you know a way to implement a queue in non-embedded C? With arrays or linked lists or whatever?

Comment: Normally I use special object to manage the queue but in a micro controller with a standard C you should manage the buffers, create the queue, enqueue and dequeue the elements.. is completely different and very hard without library

Comment: Maybe you could take a look at FreeRTOS' source code to see how they do it.

If you don't want/can't do that, the solution depends on (a) how critical it is (how much time you have to spend on this), (b) can you use dynamic memory (dynamic memory is frowned upon where I work), (c) is discarding a valid policy when the queue is full.

For the simplest solution, perhaps having pre-allocated message buffers and queue structs and using a liked list. Pre-allocation avoids pointer chasing but limits how many messages can be queued.

Comment: Would something like [this](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2017/03/08/message-queue-for-c/) work? I'd only take care to protect the queue/unqueue functions with mutexes.

Comment: What about [DMA](https://stm32f4-discovery.net/2017/07/stm32-tutorial-efficiently-receive-uart-data-using-dma/) in circle mode? It is built directly into HW.

Comment: @Leonardo c for microcontroller is different from standard c, something features are not available

Comment: @Lorenzo, yes, absolutely. With C89 you can make a message queue based on linked lists. A simple message queue will probably be enough for the OP. Other than that, you can implement OS structures like semaphores using assembly functions so you get locks/mutexes if that's not already supported by the compiler the OP is currently using. 

Embedded OS's, like FreeRTOS and uCOS have very beautiful code and can be a great learning tool. And they all run on embedded targets. So what features exactly is embedded C missing that preclude the OP from implementing a queue?

Comment: Some library are not included in the project just to reduce the memory usage. But in any case I will try, thanks

Comment: @Leonardo I don't know where to find the QUEUE_DECLARATION macro what I need to include?

Comment: @Leonardo, I verified, my C compiler supports C89 but I don't know which includes I need to manage the queue. I'm using IAR compiler for STM32

Comment: @Lorenzo What I meant is that even C89 can be used to create a queue. The C language does not have a queue build in (it's a battery excluded language), you need to build your own. If you just need a FIFO to push things on your interrupt routine and then pop them out on your main loop (which is good design BTW), I think you can check [A Simple Message Queue for C](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2017/03/08/message-queue-for-c/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- *"example on how to create e message queue (like FIFO) of strings (or byte array) using standard C and how to manage the queue"*
- *"in a micro controller with a standard C you should manage the buffers, create the queue, enqueue and dequeue the elements"*

The example given below should meet the requirements.

If necessary, the library functions used can easily be replaced with platform-specific versions or standard C array operations.

The memory allocation for the queue can also be done as static variable instead of as stack variable. If desired, even `malloc` could be used.

The message type can easily be extended. The queue and data sizes are defined as constants.

@leonardo gave a good hint on how to structure the processing, i.e. enqueuing messages in an interrupt routine and dequeuing them on main. I guess that some kind of semaphore needs to be used so that the execution of functions which manipulate the queue don't get mixed up. Some thoughts on this are discussed in [semaphore like synchronization in ISR (Interrupt service routine)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44246904/18980756)

```
/*
Portable array-based cyclic FIFO queue.
*/

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MESSAGE_SIZE 64
#define QUEUE_SIZE 3

typedef struct {
char data[MESSAGE_SIZE];
} MESSAGE;

typedef struct {
    MESSAGE messages[QUEUE_SIZE];
    int begin;
    int end;
    int current_load;
} QUEUE;

void init_queue(QUEUE *queue) {
    queue->begin = 0;
    queue->end = 0;
    queue->current_load = 0;
    memset(&queue->messages[0], 0, QUEUE_SIZE * sizeof(MESSAGE_SIZE));
}

bool enque(QUEUE *queue, MESSAGE *message) {
    if (queue->current_load < QUEUE_SIZE) {
        if (queue->end == QUEUE_SIZE) {
            queue->end = 0;
        }
        queue->messages[queue->end] = *message;
        queue->end++;
        queue->current_load++;
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

bool deque(QUEUE *queue, MESSAGE *message) {
    if (queue->current_load > 0) {
        *message = queue->messages[queue->begin];
        memset(&queue->messages[queue->begin], 0, sizeof(MESSAGE));
        queue->begin = (queue->begin + 1) % QUEUE_SIZE;
        queue->current_load--;
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    QUEUE queue;
    init_queue(&queue);

    MESSAGE message1 = {"This is"};
    MESSAGE message2 = {"a simple"};
    MESSAGE message3 = {"queue!"};

    enque(&queue, &message1);
    enque(&queue, &message2);
    enque(&queue, &message3);

    MESSAGE rec;

    while (deque(&queue, &rec)) {
        printf("%s\n", &rec.data[0]);
    }
}
```

Compiling and running:

```
$ gcc -Wall queue.c
$ ./a.out          
This is
a simple
queue!
$
```

Answer (score 1):

The C language does not have a queue build in (it's a battery excluded language), you need to build your own. If you just need a FIFO to push things on your interrupt routine and then pop them out on your main loop (which is good design BTW), Check [A Simple Message Queue for C](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2017/03/08/message-queue-for-c/) if this works for you.